# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity imports PostgreSQL timestamptz incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using an Azure Data Factory copy activity to copy data from a PostgreSQL database into Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in the parquet format. I can't seem to get columns of data type `timestamptz` imported correctly. The timestamp columns have data in this format `2022-12-08 09:44:41.812 -0600`. It appears that the values are getting converted to strings when they are copied, the values end up looking like this `2022-12-08 09:44:41.812399-06` in the parquet. I can indeed see that when I toString the values using a query like this:

`select creation_date || '' from my_table;`

The concatenation operation produces results that are the same as what I'm seeing in the parquet files that Data Factory creates, e.g. `2022-12-08 09:44:41.812399-06`.

It seems like this is a simple date format issue that could be resolved by setting the `DateTimeOffset` parameter in the mapping section of the copy activity like this:

[image]

However, this doesn't appear to have any effect. I am dynamically importing many tables, so ideally I don't want to have to map the schema for all of these tables. However, as a test, I have manually imported the schema for one table and mapped the timestamp columns as type `DateTimeOffset` in the pipeline JSON, like this:

```
{
  "source": {
    "name": "creation_date",
    "type": "DateTimeOffset"
  },
  "sink": {
    "name": "creation_date",
    "type": "DateTimeOffset",
    "physicalType": "UTF8"
  }
},
```

However, the fields are still copied in as strings that are in the incorrect format.

From what I have read, using Data Flow would give me more flexibility as far as data transformation. Unfortunately, the database I am reading from is hosted on a VM in Azure, which means I must us a "self-hosted" integration runtime to integrate Data Factory with the database. This means that I can't create a Data Flow that reads directly from the database because Data Flow doesn't support self-hosted integration runtimes. As another test, I have created a Data Flow that reads the parquet files in Data Lake Storage in an attempt to coerce the incorrectly formatted timestamp strings into a timestamp using the `toTimestamp` function in a derived column. Unfortunately, the toTimestamp function doesn't seem to be able to parse timestamps formatted like `2022-12-08 09:44:41.812399-06`. I have tried several different formats in an attempt to get the string to be parsed as a timestamp, including `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX` which I believe to be the correct format string based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#toTimestamp) that states the [Java 8 SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) expression syntax is what I should be using.

The only thing I have been able to successfully do is use string functions in a data flow to manually reconstruct the correct timestamp string from the incorrect one. However, this seems like a brittle and over-complicated approach. All I really want to do is have the Data Factory copy the timestamp values in as-is. Is there a way I can get PostgreSQL timestamptz columns copied to Parquet files in Azure Data Lake Storage by just using a Data Factory copy activity?

Comment: I think that milliseconds should be f not S. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings .

Comment: @ChenHirsh I believe it depends on whether you're formatting the date in the Data Factory Copy activity or in a Data Flow. I believe the Copy Activity uses the format you are referencing and the toTimestamp function in Data Flow uses the Java 8 syntax based on what I've read in the documentation. I have actually tried both formats however, but haven't had luck with either format in the Copy Activity or Data Flow. Have you been successful converting a timestamptz data type using the format you are referencing? If so, using which technology?

Comment: If you haven't had luck with any format in ADF, you can try formatting the date in a query instead of reading the table as is. or cast it as a different datetime type.

Comment: I'm reading hundreds of tables dynamically using Data Factory, so writing a query for all tables that have timestamps or casting specific columns seems like maintenance nightmare.